# Add custom jar grails 2.4.3

Tags: grails, groovy, monetdb

I'm adding a downloaded jar to my lib folder, but when I try to use it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
// make sure the ClassLoader has the MonetDB JDBC driver loaded
Class cls = Class.forName("nl.cwi.monetdb.jdbc.MonetDriver");
// request a Connection to a MonetDB server running on 'localhost'
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:monetdb://localhost/testDB", "monetdb", "monetdb");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
```

There is no code problems because I created a java app with same code and it works, the problem is grails is not taking the jar into the class path.
So finaly here is my buildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"


    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'

    }

    plugins {
        build ":tomcat:8.0.22"
        build(":release:3.0.1",
              ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
            export = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to use this as a db for your grails application?

Comment: I'm creating a plugin to make monetDB connection easier in any grails-app. Like the mysql or mongo plugins

Comment: Take a look at how graeme does it here: https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping

Comment: Sorry @Neoryder but I don't see how that can help me. What i'm trying to do is implementing a custom connection from a custom jar. Implementing a new gorm for monetDB (there is no one for grails yet) will take me more time and now I can't afford it (in the future I'll certainly do it but not this year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this document:
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource

Define the monetdb as a dependency using BuildConfig.groovy
by adding this 'monetdb:monetdb-jdbc:2.8'

Then update the entries in the Datasource.groovy file.

Now from your controller yuo have to inject the datasource.

```
SampleController{

def dataSource

  def index(){
      def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
      sql.executeUpdate('select * from testdb.something')
  }

}
```

Comment: What's confusing me is next line in the link you provide:  "If you can't use dependency resolution then just put the JAR in your project's lib directory."

Comment: The preferred way of dealing with dependency is by using dependency resolution. For a long time Oracle JDBC Drivers did not have a maven repository. This meant that to use it you had to put it in the lib folder.

Comment: I'm actually adding the jar to the lib folder, also added the 'monetdb:monetdb-jdbc:2.17' line to dependencies and  The error I get is : Message
No suitable driver found for jdbc:monetdb://localhost/testDB
Around line 11 of grails-app/controllers/monetdbconnector/OdbcController.groovy

8:     // make sure the ClassLoader has the MonetDB JDBC driver loaded9:   Class cls = Class.forName("nl.cwi.monetdb.jdbc.MonetDriver");10:               The error occurs with 'monetdb:monetdb-jdbc:2.17' in dependencies and without it.

Comment: But you dont call the MonetDriver like that.